# como seguir repitiendo el loop hasta que el numero sea negativo?

Tags: java

estoy tratando de crear un codigo ya que es para una tarea. como ven ya hize una parte de ella. el codigo consiste de crear un numero aleatorio de 0 a 100. Para hacer eso debo generar un random number. invente el generador de numero aleatorio utilizando el Random Class, despues debo crear un scanner class que tambien necesito para que el usuario ingrese sus datos en la consola. teniendo esos datos debo compararlos utilizando if statements. despues debo hacer una resta con el numero aleatorio menos con el numero de usuario, cree un variable difference para despues mostrarlos en la consola y despues utilizar una funcion displayData. como ven esa primera parte me salio bien, pero la segunda parte de hacer que se repita se me ha sido complicado, ya que estoy utilizando while loop  pero no se si deberia utilizar for loop. ya que imprimo los resultados me muestra la operacion solamente una vez y ya despues solo aparece "intenta de nuevo" pero sin la operacion y continua mostrandome "intenta de nuevo". y para salir del bucle necesito salir con un numero negativo. he intentado de muchas manera pero ha sido muy dificil.

espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema. se los agradeceria bastante.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Project4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Entre un numero entre 0 a 100: ");
        int user = input.nextInt();
        
        int computer;
        Random number = new Random();
        computer = number.nextInt(101);
        
        if(user > computer)
            System.out.println("El numero que entraste es correcto");
        else {
            System.out.println("El numero que entraste es bajo");
        }
        
        
        int difference = computer - user;
        displayData(user, computer, difference);
        
        input.close();
    }
    
    public static void displayData(int user, int computer, int difference) {
        System.out.printf("%d - %d = %d \n", computer, user, difference); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(computer < 100) {
            System.out.println("Intenta de nuevo");
            user = input.nextInt();             
            
        }           
                
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: al entrar en el bucle el valor de computer nunca cambia siempre sera el mismo numero menor a 100 que generaste al ejecutar tu codigo, no te seria mas practico colocar `while(user < computer)` de esa manera te aseguras de obtener un numero mayor al aleatoreo el cual es un numero correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, debes modificar la condición del bucle `while` para que se ejecute mientras el número ingresado por el usuario sea mayor o igual a cero.

Segundo, después de leer el nuevo número ingresado por el usuario, debes actualizar el valor de la variable `difference` y llamar de nuevo al método `displayData()` para mostrar los resultados actualizados.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Entre un numero entre 0 a 100: ");
        int user = input.nextInt();

        int computer;
        Random number = new Random();
        computer = number.nextInt(101);

        if (user > computer)
            System.out.println("El numero que entraste es correcto");
        else {
            System.out.println("El numero que entraste es bajo");
        }

        int difference = computer - user;
        displayData(user, computer, difference);

        input.close();
    }

    public static void displayData(int user, int computer, int difference) {
        System.out.printf("%d - %d = %d \n", computer, user, difference);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (user >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Intenta de nuevo");
            user = input.nextInt();
            difference = computer - user;
            displayData(user, computer, difference);
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```